# How to match the strings with special characters using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape website data using BS4 but can't write the exact statement to grab the link required. I want to get the link to the searched resource which should be in

```
<a href="www.speed.org">Speed Org</a>
```

The code I have written to do this is:

```
r = re.compile(r'^<a(.)*speed.org(.)*</a>$')
```

I want the code to display:

```
<a href="www.speed.org">Speed Org</a>
```

But it is not giving proper output. Can anyone please fix this code.

**Edit:**

Someone pointed out that the expression itself is wrong. The correct expression should be: `r'^<a(.*)speed.org(.*)</a>$'`
Since I was using BS4, it was easier to get the result using soup.

Thanks to all for help. :)

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML.  Chtulhu will eat your kittens and Zalgo will come for you.

Comment: Are you trying to grab the entire <a> tag or just the href value of the <a> tag?

Comment: @RyanWilson Only the value of href. If there is a better way to do it, kindly suggest.

Comment: Why is there a parenthesis around `(.)*` and which character do you expect to end up being captured? (Hint: In Python it will contain the last matched character from the repetition.)

Comment: <a.*?href="(.*?)".*

Comment: I understood the (.*) and (.), thanks for that. :D

@RyanWilson Thanks a lot. It works for me. :)

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Good, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using BeautifulSoup, don't treat the HTML as a string. Let BeautifulSoup parse it and then use `BeautifulSoup.find_all` to search for your elements:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('www\.speed\.org'))
```

`href=re.compile('www\.speed\.org')` just uses a regex to narrow down the links to those whose `href` attribute matches the regex.